# Search for one element of an ArrayList and return a List of all objects that contains that element

Tags: java, loops, search, arraylist, dictionary

The question seems trivial, but i can't find how to do it properly.

I have a `Map<Node, Integer>` memorized in a server, where each Node is defined by its hostName (a String) and its serviceList (a List of String), and port is obviously the port used by the Node. So every entry of the map gives me three informations: hostName, serviceList and port.

I'm looing for a way to search for an element, that is contained into one or more serviceLists already memorized into the map, and return a list of objects "serviceProviders". A serviceProvider is defined by hostName and port. So basically:

1. I have a Map with entries Node/Port   <---- done
2. I want to look for a service contained into one (or more) serviceLists present in the map  <---- to do
3. I want to return a List of ServiceProvider, that is basically a list of hostName and port of each Node whose serviceList contains the service i'm looking for <---- to do

I thought something like this might have worked, but it's not:

```
public List<ServiceProvider> getProvidersForService(String serviceName) throws TException {
    ServiceProvider serviceProvider = new ServiceProvider();
    List<ServiceProvider> result = new ArrayList<>();                       
    for(Map.Entry<Node, Integer> pair : nodePorts.entrySet()) {
            //problems start here               
        List<String> nodeService = pair.getKey().serviceList;
        for(String s : nodeService) {
            if(s.contains(serviceName))
                result.add(serviceProvider);
                break;
            }
        }
    return result;
}
```

which is the correct way to implement this?

Comment: First select the map keys that contain the given string in the serviceList (it's a list you could call serviceList.contains(serviceName) ) then for each of the selected nodes you create a new ServiceProvider(serviceName,map.get(node))

Comment: I suppose I have to put the list you mentioned into the if statement ?

Sorry for the noob question, i'm still learning java and i'm tad confused about some passages that are surely trivial for you experts...

Comment: You actually don't need the second for, nodeService in your code is a list, so you could just do nodeService.contains(serviceName); so if(nodeService.contains(serviceName)) result.add(new ServiceProvider(pair.getValue(),serviceName))

Comment: ok, that obviously works, but returns serviceName and port, I need it to return hostName and port. So i just modify the second part with result.add(new ServiceProvider(pair.getKey().hostName, pair.getValue()); and it should work as intended!


Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes sorry i misread it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem with your code is you are not updating your `serviceProvider` object before adding to the list, currently you are adding empty `ServiceProvider` objects:

```
public List<ServiceProvider> getProvidersForService(String serviceName) throws TException {
    ServiceProvider serviceProvider = new ServiceProvider();
    List<ServiceProvider> result = new ArrayList<>();                       
    for(Map.Entry<Node, Integer> pair : nodePorts.entrySet()) {
            //problems start here               
        List<String> nodeService = pair.getKey().serviceList;
        for(String s : nodeService) {
            if(s.contains(serviceName))
               // **update service provide before adding here by putting host/port**   
                result.add(serviceProvider);
                break;
            }
        }
    return result;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: What is in your ServiceProvider Class and Node class? i can help you in get it to work

Comment: I already got it to work, thanks to user makzikasz that commented the first post. Thank you anyway for your post, it was very useful for me to understand where I had to modify the code.

Comment: Great.. Have fun coding :)